# Formatting internal MTD storage: selecting block size?

Tags: custom-roms, file-system, partitions, formatting, system-info

I have rooted china N101-II tablet with CyanogenMod after [flashing custom ROM](http://crewrktablets.arctablet.com/?p=1913).

Internal MTD storage is 32 GiB large and custom ROM flashing make different layout to internal partitioning. Thus `/data` near 12 GiB instead of original 1 GiB (so thera are no longer need to move packages to external flash!!):

```
130|root@android:/system # df
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/system                595.4M   549.8M    45.6M   1024
/data                   11.8G   449.8M    11.4G   4096
/cache                 126M     4.1M   121.9M   4096
```

Rest space left to `/mnt/sdcard`:

```
root@android:/ # cat /system/etc/vold.fstab
dev_mount flash /mnt/sdcard auto /devices/virtual/mtd/mtd9/mtdblock9 nonremovable
```

but custom ROM flashing process left `mtdblock9` unformatted.

Under `PATH` available commands: `mkfs.ext2` and `tune2fs` so I can format myself.

`mkfs.ext2` support:

```
130|root@android:/system # mkfs.ext2 --help
mkfs.ext2 --help
BusyBox v1.21.1-jb bionic (2013-07-01 01:04 +0200) multi-call binary.

Usage: mkfs.ext2 [-Fn] [-b BLK_SIZE] [-i INODE_RATIO] [-I INODE_SIZE] [-m RESERVED_PERCENT] [-L LABEL] BLOCKDEV [KBYTES]

        -b BLK_SIZE Block size, bytes
```

According to:

```
root@android:/ # cat /proc/mtd 
cat /proc/mtd 
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00400000 00004000 "misc"
mtd1: 00800000 00004000 "kernel"
mtd2: 01000000 00004000 "boot"
mtd3: 01000000 00004000 "recovery"
mtd4: 18000000 00004000 "backup"
mtd5: 08000000 00004000 "cache"
mtd6: 300000000 00004000 "userdata"
mtd7: 00400000 00004000 "kpanic"
mtd8: 28000000 00004000 "system"
mtd9: 46fa00000 00004000 "user"
```

seems that I need to select block size as 16384 (16KiB). Am I right?

**UPDATE** Seems that `mkfs.ext2` from busybox and doesn't properly functioning:

```
android# mkfs.ext2 /dev/block/mtdblock9
mkfs.ext2: lseek: Value too large for defined data type
```

But I found `mke2fs`:

```
android# mke2fs -I 16384 /dev/block/mtdblock9
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
mke2fs: invalid inode size 16384 (min 128/max 4096)
```

In order to reduce fragmentation I try to  select larger block size (which make lesser amount of erase operation on flash I hope):

```
android# mke2fs -I 4096 /dev/block/mtdblock9
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
1162128 inodes, 4651520 blocks
232576 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=0
142 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8184 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I select largest possible block size for `mke2fs` to avoid block fractioning as erase operation on that MTD memory performed by 16 KiB chanks:

```
android# /sbin/mke2fs -t ext4 -I 4096 -O ^huge_file -m 0 /dev/block/mtdblock9
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
1162128 inodes, 4651520 blocks
0 blocks (0.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=0
142 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8184 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 35 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
```

then:

```
android# tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 /dev/block/mtdblock9
tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 /dev/block/mtdblock9
tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Setting maximal mount count to -1
Setting interval between checks to 0 seconds
```

**NOTE** There is no need to format `/data` and `/cache` partitions. That can be done automatically in `wipe data` of recovery menu.